How many Photographs on the same post?
How many pictures can be posted on the same posting?

If it's for set identification, we only need a couple provided they are detailed enough so we can identify key elements...

There's no real "technical" limitation, however you should be considerate of users bandwidth and time.
If you're trying to identify a set, a picture of each bag, or enough pictures to show the key "unique" parts is sufficient, an individual element probably only needs a single image unless there's major features on different angles.
If you can crop the images to show the relevant parts, that would be ideal.
